# Why is Ubuntu denying connections to port 21 and 22 (FTP and SSH)?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, ftp

The firewall says that the ports are both open and both services are running.  Why is this happening?

For SSH it says:

```
Connection closed by (IP) port 22
```

and for FTP it just won't load any directories or files.

Command for SSH:

```
ssh root@(IP) -i (KEY)
```

I use Filezilla FTP client, and my Ubuntu version is 18.04.

Comment: Give more detail.  What version of Ubuntu are you on.  Please give the exact error messages.  There are two reasons for this.  If you ssh you need the remote username@remotehost.  If you don't specify the remote name it will use your own name and you get denied.  Second reason is you are not actually hitting the server (remote) that you think you are because the addressing (DNS ) is wrong.

Comment: ok im totally done

Comment: Totally done?  I am willing to work with you if you are.  No pressure. Its not for everyone.   Can you paste the actual commands you are trying.  Are you on a LAN with both the computer you are on and the remote server?

Comment: the Ubuntu computer is on a VPS and ill add the commands

Comment: the commands have been added

Comment: im mainly worried about FTP i need to upload my website

Comment: OK good details.  Thanks for adding that.  I don't think the user on the VPS is root.  I think the username is the issue. I think the key you uploaded or made up there on the VPS is a  user key and not the root key.  Therefore it rejects the key.

Comment: the only way i can change it without typing it out is via FTP